# Cannot convert from byte[] to byte

Tags: java

This code seemingly compiled before:

```
private static int addTagLengthValue(int i, int length, byte[] temp, byte[] buffer, int index) {
    buffer[index++] = i;
    buffer[index++] = (byte) length;
    if (length > 0)
        buffer[index++] = temp;
    return (index);
}
```

But now I am getting these errors:

Type mismatch: cannot convert from byte[] to byte
Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte

I think I can cast i to byte but how do I deal with the temp parameter? I am simply maintaining code and these errors cropped up. Would it be due to using a different version of Java?

Comment: This `buffer[index++] = temp;` makes no sense to me. You're trying to write a whole `byte[]` on a single index of a `byte[]`?

Comment: It's impossible that this has ever compiled in any version of Java. If you're maintaining code, use your source versioning software to look back and see what was there originally that was dropped or added.

Comment: yes you can cast i to byte **buffer[index++] = (byte)i;** but no way you can convert byte[] to byte

Comment: That's what I thought but the person who wrote it swears it used to compile. I shall have to rewrite a bunch of code...

Comment: Are you trying to assign entire `temp` `byte array` to a index of `buffer`

Answer (score 1):

You have an type error. Variable `temp` should be `byte`, not `byte[]`.
Yes you can convert `int` to `byte` like that

`int i = 10;`

`byte b = (byte) i;`

But you should be sure that you don't loose significant bits.